# unexpected type: <class 'pyspark.sql.types.DataTypeSingleton'> when casting to Int on a ApacheSpark Dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm having an error when trying to cast a StringType to a IntType on a pyspark dataframe:

```
joint = aggregates.join(df_data_3,aggregates.year==df_data_3.year)
joint2 = joint.filter(joint.CountyCode==999).filter(joint.CropName=='WOOL')\
    .select(aggregates.year,'Production')\
    .withColumn("ProductionTmp", df_data_3.Production.cast(IntegerType))\
    .drop("Production")\
    .withColumnRenamed("ProductionTmp", "Production")
```

I'm getting:

> TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>         1 joint = aggregates.join(df_data_3,aggregates.year==df_data_3.year)
>   ----> 2 joint2 = joint.filter(joint.CountyCode==999).filter(joint.CropName=='WOOL')
>   .select(aggregates.year,'Production')    .withColumn("ProductionTmp",
>   df_data_3.Production.cast(IntegerType))    .drop("Production")
>   .withColumnRenamed("ProductionTmp", "Production")
>
> /usr/local/src/spark20master/spark/python/pyspark/sql/column.py in
>   cast(self, dataType)
>       335             jc = self._jc.cast(jdt)
>       336         else:
>   --> 337             raise TypeError("unexpected type: %s" % type(dataType))
>       338         return Column(jc)
>       339
>
> TypeError: unexpected type:

Answer (score 46, accepted):

PySpark SQL data types are no longer (it was the case before 1.3) singletons. You have to create an instance:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

col("foo").cast(IntegerType())
```

```
Column<b'CAST(foo AS INT)'>
```

In contrast to:

```
col("foo").cast(IntegerType)
```

```
TypeError  
   ...
TypeError: unexpected type: <class 'type'>
```

`cast` method can be also used with string descriptions:

```
col("foo").cast("integer")
```

```
Column<b'CAST(foo AS INT)'>
```

For an overview of the supported Data Types in Spark SQL and Dataframes, one can click this [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datatypes.html).

Comment: Does anyone know where you can find a list of the valid strings to pass to the `cast()`? I've looked and I find things like [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-reference.html) or [this](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/1.6/sparkr/functions/cast.html) but none of them are explicitly answering the question.

Comment: @seth127 it's better to pass an instance of spark data types, listed here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datatypes.html.