# Pyspark Error:- dataType <class 'pyspark.sql.types.StringType'> should be an instance of <class 'pyspark.sql.types.DataType'>

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to extract some data from a pipelinedRDD but while converting it to Dataframe it is giving the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/karan/Desktop/meds.py", line 42, in <module>

    relevantToSymEntered(newrdd)

  File "/home/karan/Desktop/meds.py", line 26, in relevantToSymEntered

    mat = spark.createDataFrame(self,StructType([StructField("Prescribed 

medicine",StringType), StructField(["Disease","ID","Symptoms 

Recorded","Severeness"],ArrayType)]))

  File "/home/karan/Downloads/spark-2.4.2-bin-

hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 409, in __init__

    "dataType %s should be an instance of %s" % (dataType, DataType)

AssertionError: dataType <class 'pyspark.sql.types.StringType'> should be an 
instance of <class 'pyspark.sql.types.DataType'>
```

1. Thing my error is of different type it is TypeError while I got problems with AssertionError.

2. My problem has nothing to do with casting of data types.

I've already tried using toDF() but it changes the column names which is undesirable.

```py
import findspark
findspark.init('/home/karan/Downloads/spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7')
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StringType, IntegerType, StructField, ArrayType
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
import pandas as pd

def reduceColoumns(self):
    try:
        filtered=self.rdd.map(lambda x: (x["Prescribed medicine"],list([x["Disease"],x["ID"],x["Symptoms Recorded"],x["Severeness"]])))
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error in CleanData:- ")
        print(e)
    return filtered

def cleanData(self,s):
    try:
        self.zipWithIndex
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error in CleanData:- ")
        print(e)
    return self.filter(lambda x: x[1][0]==s)

def relevantToSymEntered(self):
    mat = spark.createDataFrame(self,StructType([StructField("Prescribed medicine",StringType), StructField(["Disease","ID","Symptoms Recorded","Severeness"],ArrayType)]))
    #mat = mat.rdd.map(lambda x: (x["Prescribed medicine"],list([x["ID"],x["Symptoms Recorded"],x["Severeness"]])))
    print(type(mat))


conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("MovieSimilarities")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
spark=SQLContext(sc)
rdd = spark.read.csv("/home/karan/Desktop/ExportExcel2.csv",header=True,sep=",",multiLine="True")

print(rdd)
newrdd=reduceColoumns(rdd)
x=input("Enter the disease-")
newrdd=cleanData(newrdd,x)
relevantToSymEntered(newrdd)
```

Comment: You seem to have a class with a method called `reduceColumns` that doesn't take any input arguments, yet you give it one after your `print(rdd)` statement ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unexpected type: <class 'pyspark.sql.types.DataTypeSingleton'> when casting to Int on a ApacheSpark Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40701122/unexpected-type-class-pyspark-sql-types-datatypesingleton-when-casting-to-i)

Comment: you are missing `()` from data types - `spark.createDataFrame(self,StructType([StructField("Prescribed medicine",StringType()), StructField(["Disease","ID","Symptoms Recorded","Severeness"],ArrayType(StringType()))]))`. Also Changed `ArrayType` check

Comment: @RakeshKumar Thanks for that..... now it makes sense actually......

Answer (score 24):

`StructType([StructField("Prescribed medicine",StringType), StructField(["Disease","ID","Symptoms Recorded","Severeness"],ArrayType)])`

replace into:

`StructType([StructField("Prescribed medicine",StringType()), StructField(["Disease","ID","Symptoms Recorded","Severeness"],ArrayType())])`.

You need to instantiate the class.