# pyspark: Valid strings to pass to dataType arg of cast()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I posted this as a comment in [this semi-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40701122/unexpected-type-class-pyspark-sql-types-datatypesingleton-when-casting-to-i) but I felt it needed a post of its own.

Does anyone know where you can find a list of the valid strings to pass to the `dataType` argument of `cast()`? I've looked and I find things like [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-reference.html) or [this](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/1.6/sparkr/functions/cast.html) but none of them are explicitly answering the question.

Also, I've found through trial-and-error that you can pass things like `bigint` or `tinyint` and those seem to work, though they are nowhere listed as valid Spark data types, at least not that I can find. Any ideas?

For some reproducibility:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        [18786, "attr1", 0.9743],
        [65747, "attr1", 0.4568],
        [56465, "attr1", 0.6289],
        [18786, "attr2", 0.2976],
        [65747, "attr2", 0.4869],
        [56465, "attr2", 0.8464],
    ],
    ["id", "attr", "val"],
)
print(df)
```

This gives you `DataFrame[id: bigint, attr: string, val: double]`, I guess by inferring the schema by default.

Then you can do something like this to re-cast the types:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

fielddef = {'id': 'smallint', 'attr': 'string', 'val': 'long'}
df = df.select([col(c).cast(fielddef[c]) for c in df.columns])
print(df)
```

And now I get `DataFrame[id: smallint, attr: string, val: bigint]` so apparently `'long'` converts to `'bigint'`. I'm sure there are other conversions like that.

Also, I had this weird feeling that it would just silently ignore invalid strings you pass it, but this is *not* true. When I tried passing `'attr': 'varchar'` in the `fielddef` dict I got an `DataType varchar is not supported...` error.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of tricky to answer definitively since Spark supports complex types (Maps, Arrays, Structs) of arbitrary complexity, as well as user-defined types. For practical purposes, [DataTypeParserSuite.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/parser/DataTypeParserSuite.scala) has a pretty comprehensive set of examples for primitive and complex types.

For primitive types, I've adapted this list from the `visitPrimitiveDataType` method of [AstBuilder.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/parser/AstBuilder.scala)

- "boolean" -> BooleanType
- "tinyint" | "byte" -> ByteType
- "smallint" | "short" -> ShortType
- "int" | "integer" -> IntegerType
- "bigint" | "long" -> LongType
- "float" -> FloatType
- "double" -> DoubleType
- "date" -> DateType
- "timestamp" -> TimestampType
- "string" | "char(x)" | "varchar(x)" -> StringType
- "binary" -> BinaryType
- "decimal" | "decimal(x)" | "decimal(x.y)" -> DecimalType

Complex types are then combinations of themselves and primitive types, e.g. `struct<col1 : timestamp, col2 : bigint, col3 : map<string,array<double>>>`

Comment: Great answer! This explains why it's not clearly documented, although an incomplete list in the docs _would_ be helpful. Who was it that said "the only real documentation is the code itself?" Thanks again for the help!